# Laravel Can't Access Model Within Event Listener

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Not sure why I am having this issue, it should be a simple utilization of the `use` statement as is frequently done in Laravel controllers and repositories.

Is there something different for event listeners?

My error is:

> **Class 'App\Listeners\Asset' not found**

It fires from my event listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\FFMPEGcreateAVideo;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Models\Asset;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
class FFMPEGcreateAVideoListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  FFMPEGcreateAVideo  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(FFMPEGcreateAVideo $event)
    {
        $assetID =  $event->assetID;
        $assetURL = $event->assetURL;
        $newAssetURL = preg_replace('/(.*\.(?!.*\.))(.*)/','${1}mp4',$assetURL);
        $coverPhotoPath = $event->coverphoto;
        $asset = Asset::where("id",$assetID)->first(); //error here
```

Edit: I've tried both `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear`.

Furthermore *I know* it is this listener.

The error in full is:

> [2017-12-31 00:05:12] local.ERROR:
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class
>   'App\Listeners\Asset' not found in
>   /var/www/html/app/Listeners/FFMPEGcreateAVideoListener.php:35 Stack
>   trace

Comment: Have you tried moving the ```App\Model``` part to the actual usage instead of the ```use``` statement?

Comment: Assuming App\Models\Asset exists, this code looks fine, so are you confident this is the listener throwing the error?

Comment: did you run composer dump-autoload ?

Comment: Check namespace in `app/Models/Asset.php` file.

Comment: this isn't the file throwing that error, or at least the version you are showing of it

Comment: Try using `use App\Asset;` instead of `use App\Models\Asset;`

Comment: @Devon I am confident it is this. It is in my `laravel.log`

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi I did and yet the error persists.

Comment: @lagbox Unfortunately, it is.

Comment: @Sark `App\Asset` is not the location of my `Asset` model in my build. I reference `App\Models\Asset` in my controllers with no issue.

Comment: Try yarwest's suggestion.  From your error message and the class shown, It sounds like App\Models\Asset isn't found so it's not able to import it with use.

Comment: @Devon Tried and it didn't work. `App\Models\Asset exists`.

Comment: I rebooted Apache and my Ubuntu server and it now works. :/

Comment: so you had a version of this file that was missing this alias previously